# Wix: Open different URLs on install and uninstall

Tags: wix

I'm trying to open different URLs based when app is installed and uninstalled. Currently this setup opens both URLs when uninstalling but nothing when installing.

```
<Property Id="InstallURL">$(var.HomepageURL)install?ver=$(var.VersionNumber)</Property>
<Property Id="UninstallURL">$(var.HomepageURL)uninstall?ver=$(var.VersionNumber)</Property>

<CustomAction Id="SetOpenInstallURL" Property="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[InstallURL]" />
<CustomAction Id="SetOpenUninstallURL" Property="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[UninstallURL]" />

<CustomAction Id="OpenInstallURL" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" Return="ignore" />
<CustomAction Id="OpenUninstallURL" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" Return="ignore" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <!-- Launch webpage during install -->
    <Custom Action='SetOpenInstallURL' After='InstallFinalize'><![CDATA[Installed]]></Custom>
    <Custom Action="OpenInstallURL" After="SetOpenInstallURL"></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <!-- Launch webpage during full uninstall, but not upgrade -->
    <Custom Action="SetOpenUninstallURL" After="InstallFinalize"><![CDATA[REMOVE ~= "ALL" AND NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE]]></Custom>
    <Custom Action="OpenUninstallURL" After="SetOpenUninstallURL"></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another attempt after examining msi log at https://gist.github.com/raspi/7072ecdb43d929901e3d228893cfa124

```
<Property Id="InstallURL">$(var.HomepageURL)install?ver=$(var.VersionNumber)</Property>
<Property Id="UninstallURL">$(var.HomepageURL)uninstall?ver=$(var.VersionNumber)</Property>

<!-- Set value of WixShellExecTarget property to value of InstallURL if this is first time install -->
<SetProperty Id="WixShellExecTarget" Action="SetInstallURL" Value="[InstallURL]" Before="OpenURL" Sequence="execute">NOT Installed</SetProperty>
<!-- Set value of WixShellExecTarget property to value of UninstallURL if this is uninstall -->
<SetProperty Id="WixShellExecTarget" Action="SetUninstallURL" Value="[UninstallURL]" Before="OpenURL" Sequence="execute">REMOVE</SetProperty>

<CustomAction Id="OpenURL" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Return="ignore" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="OpenURL" After="InstallFinalize"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: This gives **error CNDL0072 : A Custom element must have a Before attribute, After attribute, or a Sequence attribute**. If I try to add `After="InstallFinalize"` then I get error **light.exe : error LGHT0001 : Found an ActionRow with a non-existent Before action: OpenURL**. Using Wix v3.10.3.3007.

Comment: After your edits: neither solution doesn't open any URLs when installing or uninstalling.

Comment: @raspi, can you share msi log of your installation session?

Comment: @raspi, thank you for sharing msi log! I messed syntax of `<SetProperty>` WiX element in my initial answer.

Comment: Ah, glad to hear problem solved finally. msi log files are very helpful for msi debugging.